# Sinon stub a function within a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I'm bringing tests to our javascript files at my place of employment. I have decided to use Mocha, Chai and Sinon libraries to help with testing. I am starting out by writing unit tests for functions that don't need too much refactoring and ran into this interesting case that I don't really understand.

```
function getQueries() {
  code that returns queries in an array -> ['one', 'two', 'three']    
}

function sort(col, type) {
  var queries = getQueries();
  some code that sorts these queries
  return sorted array
}
```

Because I am unit testing the sort function I wanted to stub getQueries() to return a dummy list.

```
var queries = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
sinon.stub(getQueries).returns(queries);
```

The above code did not work error msg:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
at Object.wrapMethod (file://node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.17.7.js:1359:29)
at Object.stub (file://node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.17.7.js:3459:26)
at F.stub (file://node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.17.7.js:4200:44)
at Context.obj.stub (file://node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.17.7.js:4215:37)
at Context.<anonymous> (unit_tests/unit_test.js:154:10)
at Context.sinonSandboxedTest (file:/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon-1.17.7.js:6069:39)
```

However, the code below did work properly.

```
var queries = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
getQueries = sinon.stub();
getQueries.returns(queries);
```

I do not fully understand why this code works while the one above it doesn't. I know the syntax of sinon.stub(obj, method, function) but the getQueries is a function without an object. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `getQueries` seems to be no part of an object, it is part of the global object `window`, so `sinon.stub(window, 'getQueries', ...)` should do the trick.

An arguably better approach in this case would be to pass the result of getQueries to the sort function. In your current structure, the `sort` function has two jobs: getting the list and sorting it. You could maybe get away with naming the function `getSortedQueries`, but actual [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is even better, and you wouldn't even need to mock or stub the function, because you can just pass a fixed list to the sort function.

Comment: Awesome ! I had tried using document as my global object but I guess its window. Thanks for the answer.